# How can I simplify this array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Just learning javascript, sorry for the beginner question!

How can I simplify the array below? I would like to add additional items to the array, but I'm getting concerned with how long the array is getting. Is there a more concise way to write this?

```
var material;

material = [
  {
    name: 'item 1'
  }, {
    name: 'item 2'
  }, {
    name: 'item 3'
  }, {
    name: 'item 4'
  }, {
    name: 'item 5'
  }, {
    name: 'item 6'
  }
];

$('.random').click(function() {
  var index;
  this.materials = $('.materials');
  index = Math.floor(Math.random() * material.length);
  this.materials.text(material[index].name);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should consider using a database instead of hardcoding it in JS.

Comment: At this point in your learning curve i wouldnt worry about databases or the length of the array.... Why not try pushing yourself further by searching through items in that array for a specific item, you could then move onto sorting objects in array based on a certain property

Comment: instead of a database, you could just use AJAX and XML to get data for the array

Comment: @Mashpoe xml? better use json than xml. A database doesn't have to be a software. It could an XML file or a JSON file. Loading it trough Ajax or even in a javascript script for json could be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your specific case, I could do something like this:

```
function toMaterial(value) {
    return {
        name: value
    }
}
var items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5']
var material = items.map(toMaterial)
```

This could help you extend the material list without taking much space, but it raise an other question... Why do you need the object with the name attribute if it's the only attribute you have. If you expect to add more attributes, this method is hardly going to help.

In every case, you'd better record those objects in a database and read them from there. The code shouldn't contain any kind of data such as this. It will also help you extend the data that is contained in the database without having to modify the code.

If an external database isn't a solution for you, you could try to build some kind of local database that will store the data in objects. And you could then export the database as a json file. Then simply load the json file and update it when you modify the database.

```
var db = {
  "materials": [
  {
    name: 'item 1'
  }
  ]
}

function output(db) {
  return JSON.stringify(db)
}

function loadDB(text) {
  db = JSON.parse(text)
}
```

And change those lines to something like:

```
index = Math.floor(Math.random() * db.material.length);
this.materials.text(db.material[index].name);
```

As for the database, there are lot of solutions out there.

Comment: Thank you. That is a good point about the object with the name attribute, it really is doing nothing. I will remove it. 

As for the database, that might be a project for another time, I'm still trying to figure out loops!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing inherently wrong with what you have here already. It just *seems* like you have a lot inside the array. Consider the following example:

```
var a = {name: "item1"};
var b = {name: "item2"};
var c = {name: "item3"};
var d = {name: "item4"};
var e = {name: "item5"};
var f = {name: "item6"};

var material = [a,b,c,d,e,f];
```

Which array do you think takes up more memory: Mine or yours?

How about this one?

```
var material = [ {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {} ];
```

It turns out that all three *arrays* take up the same amount of memory.

The reason for this is that in all three of these cases, the actual elements of the array are not the objects, but **references** to those objects. So when you do `material[3]`, you get a reference to the object at index 3 which is then followed automatically to find the object that the reference points to (`{name: "item4"}` in your original example).

That means that those objects you're storing in the array could be huge, with hundreds of properties, and the array itself would still not take up any more space.

In practice, you can store a LOT of references in an array before you run into any performance issues, so that's probably not something you need to worry about right now.

Style-wise, there are definitely better (and more scalable) ways of creating the objects and adding them to your array than by writing out the array and the objects just as one big long literal, but you don't really need to worry about performance.

I recommend learning more about Objects — specifically, how Constructors work. That way, if you needed to do this with 1000 different items, you don't have to write each out by hand. Here's how I would rewrite the construction of the array from your original program, only with 1000 elements instead of just six:

```
function Material(number) {
    this.name = "item" + number;
}

var materials = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
    var mat = new Material(i);
    materials.push(mat);
}
```